# I can't uninstall Ubuntu and I have a single boot

Tags: uninstall

I'm new to the PC-building world and I built my first PC. I didn't want to pay for Windows so I found Linux was free and Ubuntu was the best one. Well now I have Windows 8 on a USB drive and I can't uninstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to “uninstall” Ubuntu. Just let the Windows installer erase your harddisk.

If for some reason Windows can't erase the disk, boot a Ubuntu live CD (or USB), start **GParted** and erase your disk from there (**Device** → **Create Partition Table...**, select type **msdos**), after doing that the Windows installer should work fine.

Comment: my windows installer is on a USB drive and i have it plugged up in the PC. but i cant get to the setup files. and when i did it said unknown

Comment: I updated my answer, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you booting from the USB drive? If not, change your boot options in BIOS (usually esc, F10, or F12 while your computer is booting) to boot from the USB and you should be able to install Windows.

Comment: i cant even get into my BIOS. when i do it i press F2 or Delete and it goes there and tells me to press F1 and does nothing but have a black screen... im on the pc right and everything is running fine..

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you normally press F2 or delete to enter your BIOS settings? Why do you press F1 after? I would suggest consulting the manual that came with your motherboard, or consulting Google, to figure out how to change your boot drive.

Answer (score -1):

you can not uninstall something with out a device that you used to install it, need to boot from the device that you have ubuntu installed, if you had a disk or a flash drive you need change it to boot from it, then just format the drive and you will be good for a clean install of Windows 8, hope this helps :)

Comment: i noticed you said you cant get into the bios, it really depends on what machine it is, some use f8 some use f9 some use f2 some use delete, it can be different, also are you tapping it or holding it? if that doesnt work can you run your windows 8 in ubuntu and just install over the old os?